# How can I update the DOM while running intense JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm writing JavaScript which is counting up to a certain number for a project. The number could be around 100,000 and It will take roughly 10-15 seconds to complete processing.
I want the script to run as soon as the user calls the page and when the script completes it does a redirect.
Is it possible to pause for even 10ms to update the DOM while it is running to give feedback such as "Still working"?

I would like to avoid the use of jQuery and web-workers are not an option in this situation.
I realise this isn't a real world application!

EDIT: Added some of the code as a sample:

In the head:

```
function myCounter (target) {
    var t = target;
    var count = 0;
    while (t != count){
        if (t == count) {
        window.location.replace("http://example.com"); // redirect
        }
    count++;
    }
}
```

In the body:

```
<script>myCounter(100000);</script>
```

Comment: setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: javascript is single threaded. One thing can happen at a time without web workers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most browsers JavaScript and the UI run in the same thread. You can give the thread back to the browser by using `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`).

```
var myNumber = 0;
updateNumber();

function updateNumber(){
    // do heavy work for great good, ideally divided into smaller chunks

    document.getElementById('updateDiv').innerHTML = 'still working, up to ' + myNumber;

    if(myNumber < limit) {
      setTimeout(updateNumber, 20);
    }
}
```

For a lot more details on the general process, this answer is worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575011/194940

Comment: I find it best to time the "do work" to limit time (say 50ms) and then yield for some time (say 30ms). The timings will vary by browser/environment, but a 0ms (really about 5ms-15ms in imp.) timeout makes things *really choppy* in some browsers.

Comment: @pst yeah, that is probably true. I changed it to 20 milliseconds.

Comment: "In most browsers JavaScript and the UI run in the same thread" Now you've got me curious, which browsers don't the UI and JS run in the same thread?

Comment: That's what I've actually been trying to do but I can't get it to work. I added a sample of the way my code is formatted above! Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, I figured it out! Thanks :)